# how to customize dialog depending on value of property

Tags: bixby

I have a single Content view that returns objects from a Content restdb database that has a field specifying contenttype = news, facts, faq, etc.

I want the content result view to toggle to the correct phrasing depending on the value of the property.  e.g.:

```
message {

    switch (this.contenttype) {
      case (news)
      {

    if ($handsFree) {
          if (size(this) > 1)
            {
          template ("Latest headlines")
          {speech ("Latest headlines from #{value(this.identifier)}")}
        }
      else-if (size(this) == 1) 
      {template ("")
      {speech ("#{value(this.title)}. \n #{value(this.text)}")
        }}
        }
  else {
          if (size(this) > 1)
          {
          template ("Latest headlines")
          {speech ("Latest headlines from #{value(this.identifier)}")}
        }
      else-if (size(this) == 1) 
      {template ("")
      {speech ("#{value(this.title)}.")
        }}
  }
   }
    }
    switch (this.contenttype) {

       case (facts)
      {

    if ($handsFree) {        if (size(this) > 1)

            {
          template ("I found some facts")
          {speech ("Random facts from #{value(this.identifier)}")}
       }
      else-if (size(this) == 1) 
      {template ("")
       {speech ("#{value(this.title)}. \n #{value(this.text)}")
        }}
        }
  else {
          if (size(this) > 1)
           {
           template ("I found some facts")
           {speech ("Random facts from #{value(this.identifier)}")}
         }
       else-if (size(this) == 1) 
       {template ("")
      {speech ("#{value(this.title)}.")
         }}
 }
   }
    }
   }
```

However, this doesn't work. It is bringing back the system default dialog, presumably because something is not working about the switch statement.  What are some ways to make this work?

Comment: Can you add your match pattern for the result-view to your question? And also the model for the structure containing the content you want to show? It would help to see these.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code here is the test for the value of (this.contenttype).  Contenttype is an array so does not evaluate to a property value. The following code does work by simply looking at the value of the property in the first item in the array:

```
 message {

    switch (this.contenttype[0]) {
      case (news)
      {template ("news")}

       case ("facts")
      {
         if (size(this) > 1) {
      template ("I haz found facts")
    } else {
      template ("#{event(this, 'Result')}")
    }
      }

      default {template ("default is answer")
    }
```

This relies on the server correctly returning all items with the same property as intended by the query.